# Motion sequences

Tags: windows, open-source, gui, webcam, computer-vision

I'm looking for a software to script motion sequences, e.g. if you move your right hand forward press <kbd>→</kbd>. I have two normal webcams.

It must:

- Be gratis and open-source
- Detect motion of at least:

  - Face
  - Left and right arm
  - Left and right hand
  - Left and right leg
- If motion is detected, it must can:

  - Press a key on the keyboard
  - Press a key on the mouse
  - Move the cursor:

    - Left
    - Right
    - Up
    - Down
    - Left-up
    - Left-down
    - Right-up
    - Right-down
- Work on Windows 10
- Work with normal (2D) webcams
- Have an easy to use GUI